# Losing focus on HTML elements retrieved by AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, focus

I'm having problems with losing focus on the page when returning HTML using AJAX calls with jQuery. This results in two clicks being required to use any of the injected links. Using .focus() on the returned elements doesn't appear to have an effect. I solved a similar problem previously (that resulted in buttons needing to be clicked twice) by using prependTo but this doesn't seem to work in this instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

```
 $('input#5000').click(function(){
               //Run SQL query
            $

            $.ajax({    
                type:    'POST',    
                url:     '/querytorun/',   
                data:    'querytorun='+$('p#3000').html(), 
                //Either display error message or results
                error:   function(){ $('p#4000').html("Can't run SQL query"); },    
                success: function(data) { 
                    $('p#4000').html(data); 
                    $('div').remove('.qbb');
                    $('<div class = qbb><input id="email_btn" type="button" onClick="window.location=\'email_form_list/\'" value="Email Users" /></div>').prependTo('#export_query_wrapper');
                    $('<div class = qbb><input id="csv_btn" type="button" onClick="window.location=\'csv_export/\'" value="Export CSV" /></div>').prependTo('#export_query_wrapper');
                }    
            });               
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: As a side note, `$('input#5000')` is less efficient than `$('#5000')`. There's no need to put anything to the left of an id selector. Also, "5000" is not a valid id. Ids must not begin with a number. The same goes for `$('p#4000')`.

Comment: where do you want the focus to be after the ajax call completes?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In querytorun I'm echoing out a table of links. The focus seems to go from the page completely meaning that an additional click is required to get focus on the page (essentially it doesn't matter where the focus actually is as long as it's on the page somewhere).

Comment: It turns out that using buttons instead of links solved the problem. Not sure why that is but for the time being the problem's solved.

Comment: It seems that the browser will not capture/trigger any events happening while ajax is being executed.